# ant tar, exclude content of a folder but include the folder itself

Tags: ant

What's the right include/exclude pattern to exclude content of a folder but include the folder itself ?

for example,
I want to exclude all classes and all the package structure in WEB-INF/classes, but keep the folder itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following directory str.:

..\ tarring \ xyz \ folder-A;
..\ tarring \ xyz \ folder-B;
...
..\ tarring \ xyz \ folder-X;

```
<tar basedir="..\tarring\xyz" destfile="..\tarring\xyz.tar">            
    <exclude name="folder-X/**/*"/>
</tar>
```

`folder-X:`  the folder which is to be included in the tar file, but without its contents

`xyz.tar` will contain all the contents within the `..\ tarring \ xyz` folder, along with an empty ***folder-X***.

- `<exclude name="folder-X/**/*"/> :` includes ONLY `folder-X` and **not** inner files or sub-directories
- `<exclude name="folder-X/**/*.*"/> :` includes `folder-X` along with **all sub-directories under it**. However, excludes ALL files within folder-X and its sub-directories.
- `<exclude name="folder-X/*.*"/> :` includes `folder-X` and **any sub-directories within folder-X, along with all their contents** BUT **excludes all FILES** directly under folder-X